# Detect access token expiration when invoking Google APIs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have a Google Apps Script that is deployed as API Executable. I am able to invoke it from my java based web application. But, it fails **only sometimes** with `Authorization is required to perform that operation`. I have done the analysis and found that it fails because Apps Script returns this error if the access token expiration time is less than 6 minutes. There is a reason behind why Apps Script behaves this way, which is beyond the scope of this question. But, the solution to this is to generate a new `access_token` if the expiration time is less than 6minutes.

I am using Java Google Client Library to manage the access tokens:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                                    .setClientSecrets("<<clientId>>", "<<clientSecret>>")
                                    .build();
credential.setRefreshToken("<<refresh_token>>");
```

Using the above `credential` I am creating the `Script` object:

```
Script scriptService = new Script.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("test").build();
```

Invoke the Apps Script:

```
scriptService.scripts().run("test script");
```

The client library takes care of generating the access token, store it in-memory and on expiration invokes the OAuth API to generate a new token.

Now, I would need your suggetions to:

1. check if the expiration time of the access token is less than 6 minutes
2. if yes, then generate the new access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code to find the remaining time for the token to expire and generate the new access token:

> check if the expiration time of the access token is less than 6 minutes

```
credential.getExpiresInSeconds()
```

> if yes, then generate the new access token

```
credential.refreshToken()
```

Comment: anything similar for the web server oauth client library?